# Create a text file using TFileStream

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, tfilestream

I tried code from the following documentation:

[Reading a String and Writing It To a File](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/win32_rwfilestream_xml.html)

But it doesn't work and reports a compiler error:

> No member named 'fmCreate' in 'System::AnsiStringT<0>'

Here is the code I tried:

```
TFileStream *fs; const AnsiString str = "Hello";
fs = new TFileStream("temp.txt", fmCreate);
fs->Write ((void*)str.c_str(), str.fmCreate);
```

Comment: Funny, what you linked to is REALLY old documentation, but the [latest version](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Reading_a_String_and_Writing_It_To_a_File) has the same typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it just looks like a typo. Clearly the code is trying to write the string to the file, so the length of the string is needed. Try this

```
TFileStream *fs; const AnsiString str = "Hello";
fs = new TFileStream("temp.txt", fmCreate);
fs->Write ((void*)str.c_str(), str.Length());
```

Caveat, I know nothing about VCL.

Comment: This is the correct way to fix the typo. Also, the `void*` type-cast is not needed, as `Write()` takes a `const void*` and the `const char*` from `c_str()` is implicitly convertible to `const void*`, eg: `fs->Write (str.c_str(), str.Length());` Although, I would suggest using `WriteBuffer()` instead, which will throw an exception if it fails to write out the entire string, eg: `fs->WriteBuffer (str.c_str(), str.Length());`

Answer (score 0):

As John's answer states, there is a typo in the documentation.  `str.fmCreate` should be `str.Length()` instead.

However, there are better ways to write a string to a text file that avoid this issue.  For instance, by using [`System::Classes::TStreamWriter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter) or [`System::Ioutils::TFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <System.Classes.hpp>

const String str = _D("Hello");
TStreamWriter *sw = new TStreamWriter(_D("temp.txt"), false, TEncoding::UTF8);
sw->Write (str);
delete sw;
```

```cpp
#include <System.IOUtils.hpp>

const String str = _D("Hello");
TFile::WriteAllText(_D("temp.txt"), str);
```